# How to compare 2 Dates in filter? SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have a column named `Birthday` and I have created a calculated calumn named `BirthGET` its formula is: `=TEXT(Birthday,"dd/mm").`for example a field in `Birthday` column would be `28/05/1998`, now the value in `BirthGET` would be `28/05` this logic is working nice, but I have  a problem.

I have added a content query web part, and I want to filter like this, if todays day and month `is equal to` `BirthGET` show that item.

[image]

How can I make this?

Comment: Just to veify, I presume you want the CQWP because you are querying Multiple Lists and/or want to display the results on another Site? If not it is easier to do this in a regular List View (but that would be a View on One List on the Same Site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
[Birthday] is equal to DATE(YEAR([Birthday]),MONTH([TODAY],DAY([TODAY]))
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: `Please specify one of the following [PageFieldValue: (field name)] or [PageQueryString: (query string parameter name)] or an integer value for setting up a dynamic date range for date fields.`

Comment: Another option would be to have calculated fields "BirthdayMonth" and "BirthdayDay" and then specify two filter rules

Comment: @NderonHyseni take a look at this: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/filtering-and-sorting-sharepoint-list-views

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the calculated field BirthGet for this purpose.

You should use a Date field and check if it equals `[Today]`

Comment: no this one will not work because I have only `dd/mm` and `[Today]` has `dd/mm/yy` and this is not working

Comment: Please read answer properly. You can't use calculated field in the filter because it is a Text and not date object

Comment: Thanks but what should I do in this case?

Comment: Use the date field. I know you derived BirthGet using a Date field.

Comment: Could you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1):

You got two options :)

Either using a custom display template or using JSLink

Display Template:

I believe Birthday column has the year so the solution suggested by Patrick won't work! Honestly, Copy  one of the existing display templates and apply that logic easily there and only display the desired result (parsing dates in javascript and doing date compare should be easy and lots of resources are out there on the web on how to do that). The solution is going to query the user profile for the Birthday field and do the calculation based on Today's date. If you dont have the user profile birthday property populated or not configured, you can tweak the solution to query the column you already has created.

https://joranmarkx.wordpress.com/2013/10/02/show-upcomming-birthdays-based-on-sharepoint-2013-user-profiles-with-search-office365/

or

http://www.lestersconyers.com/birthdays-and-anniversaries/

JSLink:

Create a custom function in the JSLink file that will query the `ctx.CurrentItem.Birthday` and compare it to current date var `currentDate = new Date();`( you need to parse the date using JavaScript and do the comparison) like this:

http://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Insights/Skyline-Blog/February-2015/Use-JS-Link-to-Create-a-Current-Birthdays-View